# How change property from label in RadListView

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I'm trying to access the property of the label in RadListView to change it. Depending on whether the are true or false, the color should change.

I tried to get the reference with getViewById to change the properies.
The result i get is undefined. How can i access property in RadListView ?
Seen is a variable that is currently set to true

## .JS

```
function createViewModel(args) {
    const viewModel = new Observable();
    
    //Prüft, ob die Artikel gesehen wurden 
    
    viewModel.set("itemss", itemss);

    if(Seen==true){
        const page = args.page;
        const label = page.getViewById("test");
        label.color = "green";
        
    }
    if(Seen==false){
      const page = args.page;
      const label = page.getViewById("test");
      label.color = "red";
    }

    






    return viewModel;
}
```

## XML

```
<Page xmlns:lv="nativescript-ui-listview" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:FAB="nativescript-floatingactionbutton" xmlns:sd="nativescript-ui-sidedrawer" class="page" loaded="pageLoaded" xmlns:customControls="shared">
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar icon="" class="action-bar">
        <label text="ZorrasBistro" class="actionlabel"/>
        <ActionItem tap="NewButtonTap" class="btn" ios.position="right" android.position="right"> 
        <label class="fas" style ="padding-right:20em; font-size:20em; color:grey" text="&#xf067;"/>
        </ActionItem>
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>
    <sd:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer">
    <sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
        <customControls:sidedrawer/>
    </sd:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
    <sd:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <lv:RadListView items="{{itemss}}" id="listview" height="350" row="1" class="list-group" selectionBehavior="Press" multipleSelection="false" itemSelected ="onItemSelected" >
                    <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
                        <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" itemInsertAnimation="Slide" />
                    </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
                    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                        <GridLayout class="list-group-item" rows="auto" columns="auto,*" backgroundColor="White">
                            <Image row="0" col="0" src="{{itemSrc}}" class="thumb img-rounded" />
                            <StackLayout  row="0" col="1">
                                <Label  text="{{itemName}}" class="list-group-item-heading" />
                                <label text="{{itemDesc}}" class="list-group-item-text" />
                                <label  id="itemid" text="{{id}}" class="list-group-item-text"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <label id="test" row="0" col="3" text="&#xf056;" class="fas" color="green" style="padding-top:25em;color:black;opacity:0.2;"  verticalAligment="bottom" horizontalAlignment="right" />
                            </GridLayout>
                    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                    <lv:RadListView.itemSwipeTemplate class="Grid">
                        <GridLayout columns="auto, *, auto">
                            <StackLayout col="0" id="save" class="save-btn" tap="onLeftSwipe" orientation="horizontal">
                                <Label text="Details" id="save-text" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout col="2" id="delete" class="delete-btn" tap="onRightSwipe" orientation="horizontal">
                                <Label text="Delete" id="delete-text" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </GridLayout>
                    </lv:RadListView.itemSwipeTemplate>
                </lv:RadListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </sd:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
    </sd:RadSideDrawer>
</Page>
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getViewById' of undefined
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bestellung-overview/bestellung-overview-view.js, line: 40, column: 27

StackTrace:
        Frame: function:'createViewModel', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bestellung-overview/bestellung-overview-view.js', line: 40, column: 28
        Frame: function:'_pageLoaded', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/bestellung-overview/bestellung-overview.js', line: 13, column: 27
        Frame: function:'Observable.notify', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js', line: 110, column: 23
        Frame: function:'Observable._emit', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js', line: 127, column: 18
        Frame: function:'ViewBase.onLoaded', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 236, column: 14
        Frame: function:'View.onLoaded', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js', line: 235, column: 35
        Frame: function:'Page.onLoaded', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/page/page.js', line: 43, column: 35
        Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 311, column: 90
        Frame: function:'ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 304, column: 9
        Frame: function:'ViewBase.callLoaded', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 311, column: 14
        Frame: function:'ViewBase.loadView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 439, column: 18
        Frame: function:'ViewBase._addViewCore', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 434, column: 18
        Frame: function:'ViewBase._addView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js', line: 420, column: 14
        Frame: function:'FragmentCallbacksImplementation.onCreateView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 658, column: 19
        Frame: function:'FragmentClass.onCreateView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/fragment.js', line: 26, column: 38


        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
        at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1203)
        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1083)
        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1070)
        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1050)
        at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1042)
        at com.tns.FragmentClass.onCreateView(FragmentClass.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `ListView` / `RadListView` you should not access an element by its id nor manually change a property of item by its reference. You should always update the data and bind the appropriate attribute to `Label` / any component within item template.

```
<label id="test" row="0" col="3" text="&#xf056;" class="fas" style="padding-top:25em;opacity:0.2;"  verticalAligment="bottom" horizontalAlignment="right" color="{{ itemColor }}"  />
```

Update `itemColor` as needed so it updates the label within list item automatically.

Regarding the exception, I'm not sure how / where you are calling `createViewModel` method. But you should be passing the `page` attribute in `args`, if you are directly passing the `args` from page loaded event then `args.object` should give you the reference to page.

Comment: Can I also include individual things in RadListView? Or is it just an entire array with the properties then involved? Would you like to do the following if (Seen == true) { viewModel.set ("itemColor", "green"); }. But I get Property: 'itemColor' is invalid or does not exist. @Manoj